# How to install Eclipse on OSX 10.9.4

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I've seen similar questions, but nobody having the identical problem...

- I installed eclipse.
- Attempted to run, and it complained I had no Java engine (oops).
- It offered to install Java 6. I accepted the offer and it did.
- When I tried to run eclipse again it complained that it needed Java 7.
- Downloaded and installed Java 7. It is the only version that shows in preferences.
- Try to run eclipse again. It continues complaining that Java 6 is not sufficient and it requires Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve what you want. But just to add some options, you can achieve it without modifying the default java version.

You can use the

```
-vm
/path/to/jdk7/bin/java
```

Here you can see more examples http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini.

The file is in `/opt/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini` (note that my `eclipse` installation is in /opt/eclipse).